# $page in controller calling view file (CodeIgniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I have a question, 
what does ***$page*** purpose in here?

```
public function user_defined($page = 'view_file.php')
{
    #Syntax
}
```

is ***$page*** a user_define too or a fixed// function in CI?

Sorry if this has already an answer, I'm exploring CI

Comment: this isn't a CI function afaik - this has to be one of your controllers function - besides of that - what is your actual question ?

Comment: what does $page purpose? XD is it used to call view pages? @sintakonte

Comment: in order to answer that - you've to provide the whole function here - or rather the entire class

Comment: @LapiztheProgrammer $page is a variable and used for parameter with 'view_file.php' as default value. and this is not related with CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) if you define parameterized function you have to pass the parameter like below

```
public function user_defined($page)
{
    #Syntax
}
```

in this case if you call this function without parameter it will respond with fatal error.

2) If you define optional parameterized function you can pass parameter or not

```
public function user_defined($page = 'view_file.php')
{
    #Syntax
}
```

in this case if you call this function without passing parameter it will respond without any error.